# MKMapView get zoom level in feet per screen inch

Tags: ios, mkmapview, zooming, mapkit

I am trying to figure out the zoom level of an MKMapView in feet per screen inch. Has anyone done anything like this before, or know of any quick categories which would provide this type of behavior?

Comment: The MKMetersBetweenMapPoints function may be useful here (get the mappoints using the map view's visibleMapRect).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. use `MKMetersPerMapPointAtLatitude / Longitude` to get meters/point
2. use the view width too see how many points
3. use device dimension to get points/per inch to get meters/inch
4. lastly convert that to feet and your good

Answer (score 0):

You can also make use of the fact that there are about 110,000 meters per degree latitude (longitude distance varies based on latitude, i.e. varying from equator to poles). You could then figure out the current vertical span and do some math on that.